# Calling IfError with vLookUp in VBA returns error even though cell formula returns value

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm using `ifError` coupled with `vLookUp` to look for values in a large table and pull out a value from a specific column to be placed in a specific cell in another worksheet.

This is my current code for drawing value from column no 9 starting from column D, to be placed into another worksheet's cell B14.

```
Sheet3.Range("B14").Value = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(Sheet3.Range("B4"), Sheet2.Range("D5:CU530"), 9, False), "Not Found")
```

This code returns "Not Found" for me.

Further testing using the similar formula but placed directly into a random cell returns the true value. Below is the formula used.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B4,'Sheet 2 Name'!D5:CU530,9,FALSE),"Not Found")
```

The same vba code (as shown in first block quote) used for other columns (eg column 2/3/4) are returning the true value instead of "Not Found", even when the destination cell is Sheet 3's B14.

Any ideas why?

Edit: More information
If I were to use vLookUp alone in VBA (see next code), I can get the true value, but I will need the IfError as there will be situations where no value are found.

```
 Application.VLookup(Sheet3.Range("B4"), Sheet2.Range("D5:CU530"), 9, False)
```

Comment: Actually your first piece of code says `Sheet3.Range("B14").Value` so you put this into `B14` instead of `B4`

Comment: Ah my bad, typo. I want it to be at B14.

Comment: The code seems fine to me. Maaaaybee the `Application.IfError` + the `Application.VLookup` (as in using the `Application` object twice in the same command) causes the error, but I wouldn't know why. As a workaround I would suggest running the `VLOOKUP` without the `IFERROR` and check for erros afterwards.

Comment: Hmm that's weird though, because in other cells I'm calling the same command but just gathering data from another column instead of column 9, and it is working. I'll keep troubleshooting and update the post here. thanks for the suggestion though, appreciate it

Comment: Perhaps it is something related with the value expected to be returned. Would you tell us what's the value that should be returned from column 9. Somehow it seems that the `VLookup` is returning the correct value but value in column 9 is seen as an error by the `IfError` function.

Answer (score 0):

You could do without `IfError` and do an `if statement` after your `Vlookup` instead:

```
x = Application.VLookup(Sheet3.Range("B4"), Sheet2.Range("D5:CU530"), 9, False)

If IsError(x) Then
    Sheet3.Range("B14").Value = "Not found"
Else
    Sheet3.Range("B14").Value = x
End If
```

Comment: Hmm, that could be an alternative! Thanks! I still wanna figure out why it isn't working though..

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error may lie in the vlookup section, vlookup as a much older section of code (i.e. an older version of VB) and where you can, I would really encourage the use of an index match combo, as it is much more specific in what you look for (and more efficient)!

Here is a link to information on Index

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197581.aspx

and Match

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

use on error funtion

```
On Error Resume Next

ws.Range("B14").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws.Range("B2").Value, ws.Range("E:F"), 1, False), "No error")
```